# Relay: How to merge instead of override queries in nested routes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql-js, relayjs, react-router-relay

I cannot navigate to `/users` in my app, because it doesn`t trigger fetching of all queries that I would expect it should.

My app consists of an `App` component and some components that contain actual content like `Dashboard` or `UserList`. There is also an `EnsureAuthenticationContainer` but this is just a component that, when a user is authenticated, simply renders it's children. This is my route setup:

```
const ViewerQueries = {
    viewer: () => Relay.QL`query { viewer }`
};
```

[...]

```
<Router history={browserHistory} render={applyRouterMiddleware(useRelay.default)} environment={Relay.Store}>
    <Route path="/" component={App} queries={ViewerQueries}>
        <Route path="login" component={Login} />
        <Route component={EnsureAuthenticationContainer}>
            <IndexRoute component={Dashboard} />
            <Route path="users" component={UserList} queries={ViewerQueries} />
            <many more routes />
        </Route>
    </Route>
</Router>
```

The problem is, that both `App` and `UserList` have defined fragements and it seems that only the query of `UserList` is send.

Fragment of `App`:

```
fragments: {
    viewer: () => {
        return Relay.QL`
            fragment on ViewerType {
                loggedInUser {
                    id
                }
            }
       `;
    }
}
```

Fragment of `UserList`:

```
fragments: {
    viewer: () => Relay.QL`
        fragment on ViewerType {
            id,
            users(first: $limit) {
                edges {
                    node {
                        id,
                        userName,
                        firstName,
                        lastName,
                        eMail
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    `,
}
```

How can I setup React/Relay/Router to query both `users` and `loggedInUser`?

**Update**

I use react-router@3.0.5 and react-router-relay@0.13.7

**Update #2**

This is the only query Relay generates when I visit "/users" and which is send to the server:

```
query Index {
  viewer {
    id,
    ...F0
  }
}
fragment F0 on ViewerType {
  _users2quBPZ:users(first:100) {
    edges {
      node {
        id,
        userName,
        firstName,
        lastName,
        eMail
      },
      cursor
    },
    pageInfo {
      hasNextPage,
      hasPreviousPage
    }
  },
  id
}
```

The response matches the query:

[image: The response from the server]

Comment: What's your output in the "Network" tab (assuming you use Chrome)? Is there just one query or two? Please post the request payload and the response.

Comment: Yes, there is only one query. I just posted what Relay generates and what is returned from the server.

Comment: Why don't you just add `loggedInUser { id }` under your `userList` query? Relay isn't fetching `loggedInUser` because your active component (`UserList`) doesn't ask for it.

Comment: The `UserList` component does not and should not know anything about logged in user. Even if I add `loggedInUser` to it, `App`, which is intended to display the current user, it still does not get `loggedInUser` injected as prop then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm totally not sure but I would have done like this :

fragment of App :

```
fragments: {
  viewer: () => {
    return Relay.QL`
      fragment on ViewerType {
        loggedInUser {
          id
        }
        ${UserList.getFragment("viewer")}
      }
    `;
  };
}
```

I think this example repo is going to be helpful to you : https://github.com/taion/relay-todomvc/blob/master/src/components/TodoApp.js#L60-69

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But won't your solution blow up the fragment of App when my application will consists of many more routes besides the UserList?

Comment: I don't think so because "react-router-relay will automatically generate a combined Relay query config with all queries and parameters from the active React Router routes, then pass down the query results to each of the route components". (https://github.com/relay-tools/react-router-relay#usage)

Comment: Thanks. I just tried that but navigating to "/" triggered the `users` field to be queries, although the component was not meant to be rendered.

Comment: Does changing your `queries` prop in your Route `<Route path="users" component={UserList} queries={UsersQueries} />` with `const UsersQueries = {
    viewer: () => Relay.QL`query { viewer { users } }`
};`  work ?

Comment: No, it doesn't change anything.

Comment: This answer could not help me much in solving the problem, but as you, Vincent, are the only person that really tried to help, the bounty goes to you. ;-)